# Merge data into one column - sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

How can I merge data into one column for different account numbers. Currently, it looks like this.

```
TableA.Order  TableA.Question  TableB.Response
1             a                Null
1             b                James
1             c                Null
2             d                Zebra
2             T                Null
```

However, I want it to merge like below:

```
 TableA.Order  NewColumn
   1             a
   1             b
   1             c
   1             James
   2             d
   2             T
   2             Zebra
```

Comment: So you want all non-null values from columns `Question` and `Response`? Can you show us what you've tried already?

Comment: How do you intend to tell which Question goes to which Response in the NewColumn?

Comment: PLZ specify more, exactly what do you want: you want update a table?, create a new table?, or you want a select? or etc...?you need to clarify more, i.e: show the queries you tried or the table structure to be able to understand you well and give a detailed solution for you

Comment: I need a select statement to combine two columns into one. I have a long script and trying to summarize to a point here. I can't post my work queries here due to privacy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base from my understanding of your question. I devised a solution which answers to it. See my query below:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
UNION ALL
SELECT B.Order1,A.Response From 
   (
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Response)PK,* FROM TableB) A Left Join 
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Order1)PK,* FROM TableA) B On A.PK=B.PK 
   )
Where Response IS NOT NULL
```